# Copy and Paste is making new tortoise svn projects

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I copy an svn directory for tortise the svn icons are still showing up.  How can I copy the directory without the svn information being copied as well?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, there's an "Export" option.  If you right-click-drag-and-drop a folder with Tortoise installed you'll see the export option.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to just do an svn export (its in the tortoise svn menu) of the folder. Otherwise you'll have to in and delete all the little .svn folders that these folders have that give those folders to smarts to know that they are svn folders and where they point back to.

Export works just like a checkout except it "detaches" it from subversion and just gives you the contents.

Answer (score 7):

IN SHORT: 
Use "Export" feature to get a copy of svn directories and files.
OR
Copy folder and then manually delete svn hidden folders from it.

EXPLAINED:
When you do a "Check out", Tortoise puts in each checked out folder a hidden folder where it keeps the "base version" of the folder's content. This way it can detect changes you made to files under source control. To see this hidden folders, you need to set your file explorer to show hidden files and folders. Also, this way the Tortoise can show you the status icons.

There is another way you can get the files from the source control repository. It is the **"Export"** feature. With this option you get the latest version of the files from the server, but WITHOUT the hidden folders. Be cautious, though, that you will not be able to commit changes to files exported via "Export". (but you can add them as new files, if needed)

If you just want to make a copy of the files (but loose the SVN tracking facility), I would recommend you use the "Export" feature. But, in case you no longer have connectivity with the svn server, you might as well delete by hand all hidden folders from the copied directory.

Answer (score 2):

It is called export commad. It will ask you for a directory where to place the copy. If you select the same dir as your svn dir it will actually remove the svn data alltogether.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to delete the "hidden" .svn directories beneath each folder (after you've copied the directory, of course).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just delete the .svn folders from a large project, you can use my script, my cmd line script based on [John Galloway's](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/24/shell-command-remove-svn-folders.aspx) explorer extension:

```
:: unsvn 1.0 - By Casey Dunham (http://www.caseydunham.net)
:: 
:: usage - unsvn folder
::
:: Deletes all .svn folders under the specified folder.
::
:: 
:: Based on a Windows command shell extension by John Galloway
:: at http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/24/shell-command-remove-svn-folders.aspx
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
if /i "%1" == "" goto usage

for /r %1 %%f in (.svn) do (
    if exist %%f (
        echo removing %%f
        rd /s /q %%f
    ) else (
        echo.File %%f not found!
        goto done
        )
    )

:usage
echo unsvn 1.0
echo usage: unsvn folder
echo.
echo Deletes all .svn folders and files below the specified folder.

:done
```

Just save the above as unsvn.bat, put it in your path and pass it the top level folder from where you would like all of the .svn folders to be removed from.

Comment: just noticed that this is only checking for .svn folders. I believe you can set options to use _svn folders instead so you may want to modify the if statement to check for that.